# how to download the audio of Bing translator's text to speech

Tags: google-chrome, bing

https://bing.com/translator

I already knew that we can record it use whatever apps that can do it.

but I want to know can we find the audio file in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bing Translator's webform sends a request and has the mp3 returned "on the fly" base64-coded. You can manually retrieve that and decode it into the mp3.

As of now (DevTools change over time), this works:

1. Open [bing.com/translator](https://www.bing.com/translator)
2. Open the dev console on that tab & open its *Network* tab
3. Set the translator to the language + terms you want & click the speak button
4. A *"v1"* will pop up under *"Names"*
5. Right click & *"Save all as HAR with content"*
6. Open it with a text editor
7. Search for `"mimeType": "audio/mpeg"`
8. The entire `"text"` string is the encoded mp3 (starting with `//` and typically ending with a lot of `q`s).

On Linux & co., you can decode it by saving it to a text file (say, `in.txt`) and running `base64 --decode in.txt > out.mp3` on console.

(Somehow the base64 decode websites Google turns up only produce garbage as output.)

Answer (score 0):

The audio file is not readily available in the browser.  The possibility of pulling it out in some manner is high as solutions have been created for streaming video to work around the obfuscation and chunking done by streaming services like Youtube and Vimeo however the overhead required likely makes this untenable for the average user.

For example, here is a thread to a solution for Google's TTS that began in 2018 as simply as saving a .wav file from the browser cache but in 2022 now requires a much more complicated process involving decoding base64 to wav ([link to answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1352853/how-can-i-download-audio-from-google-s-sample-text-to-speech/1654611#1654611))

Given that you are already aware of tools and browser extensions that can be used to record the audio stream as it is being played, I am suggesting that you use a different tool to generate the TTS audio files.  One that is designed to create downloadable files.

In particular the options **From Text To Speech** and **MarryTTS Online Demo**, while not including translation, will quickly and easily give you a way to generate and download TTS audio files with minimal knowledge.  For translation you can continue to use your preferred online text translator to generate the text.

If you are comfortable using, or willing to learn an API, the **MaryTTS** project as well as **IBM Watson** and **Microsoft's Cognitive Services** can be adapted to your needs.

I myself tried IBM's API via curl some time ago when I needed to generate some audio files for my IOT setup.  I was pretty green but it was easily manageable by setting up a free account.

Here are the options I mentioned:

#### [image: From Text to Speech Logo]

#### From Text To Speech

No translation but free online text to speech (TTS) service with natural sounding voices ([fromtexttospeech.com](http://www.fromtexttospeech.com/)).  Easy to use and download files.  Some voice customization supported depending on language.

```
  Languages Supported: 
  ===================
  French   US English
  Spanish  UK English
  German   Portuguese
  Italian  Russian
```

---

#### [image: MARYTTS Web Client Logo]

#### MaryTTS

[MarryTTS Online Demo](http://mary.dfki.de:59125/)
Online demo of the Mary Text-to-Speech System.
Languages are selected by changing the voice in the drop menu to your preferred.
Audio files can be downloaded by right-clicking.

MaryTTS is an open-source, multilingual Text-to-Speech Synthesis platform written in Java.  As of version 5.2, MaryTTS supports German, British and American English, French, Italian, Luxembourgish, Russian, Swedish, Telugu, and Turkish; more languages are in preparation.

[MaryTTS Website](http://mary.dfki.de/)
[MaryTTS Github project](https://github.com/marytts/marytts).

---

#### [image: Speech Studio Logo]

#### Microsoft's Speech Studio (Azure Cognitive Services)

Instead of using their translation web tool, generate the files yourself using their API.  Text to speech and translation with more than 400 voices across 140 languages and dialects.

Requires licensing and diving into the documentation.
[Microsoft Speech Studio](https://speech.microsoft.com/portal) 
[Microsoft Azure Text to Speech](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/index-text-to-speech)

---

#### [image: IBM Watson Logo]

#### IBM Watson Text to Speech

IBM Watson Text to Speech ([www.ibm.com/cloud/watson-text-to-speech/](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/watson-text-to-speech)) allows you to convert convert text into natural-sounding speech in a variety of languages and voices.  Signup is free and if you don't use more than 10,000 Characters per Month you don't need to get a paid plan.

You will need to use the API to download audio so the learning curve is there but the documentation is good and the work can be done using simple curl commands or coded into a basic HTML page if you have the skills and want more automations.

The IBM site might appear daunting but I found I got up and running quickly when I used it previously.

[IBM Watson TTS Resources](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/watson-text-to-speech/resources)